# Socket receiving in while 1

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create socket connections in python. I need to listen to server until it sends a message, thus I need to use `while True`. 
Client:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import socket

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pinLDR = 7
pinLED = 11
touch = False
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.1.67', 9092))

while True:
    print sock.recv(256)

def rc_time ():
    count = 0

    GPIO.setup(pinLDR, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pinLDR, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    GPIO.setup(pinLDR, GPIO.IN)

    while (GPIO.input(pinLDR) == GPIO.LOW):
    count += 1

    return count

def led(lh):
    GPIO.setup(pinLED, GPIO.OUT)
    if lh == 1:
        GPIO.output(pinLED, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        GPIO.output(pinLED, GPIO.LOW)

try:
    while True:
        print(str(rc_time()))
        if rc_time() > 5000:
            if touch == False:
                print "triggered"
                sock.send("triggered")
                touch = True
        else:
            if touch == True:
                sock.send("nottriggered")
                print "nottriggered"
                touch = False
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
sock.close()
```

But I have a problem with it. Nothing is printed even if a server sends a message. And the whole code after first `while True` doesn't work

Comment: I think you want something like `msg = sock.recv(256); if msg: print msg`. Here you're consuming the data and then trying to consume it again.

Comment: If my hunch is right, this program will print every other message it receives.

Comment: @smarx No, that doesn't work. And the whole code after these strings also doesn't work

Comment: See my answer below. A loop like I described definitely works, so the problem must be outside of the code you've shared. Please share the rest of your code if you haven't already figured out the issue.

Comment: BTW, `recv` is blocking, so if you just need to receive one message, there's no need for a loop. Similarly, there's no real need for the `if` test at all. (And as previously mentioned, the `if` consumes the data, so you'll miss half of the messages that are sent.)

Comment: If this updated code doesn't work, your server isn't sending anything.  What does the server code look like? The answer given by @smarx code is correct.  `recv` is blocking, so if you don't recieve anything, the remaining code will not execute as you are seeing.

Comment: @MarkTolonen the server sends message only if it receives message from client. In the client code, after `sock.send("nottriggered")`, it can receive a message from the server. But only in that place

Comment: Well that explains it then.  You left out that important piece of information.   The `recv` blocks because a message hasn't been sent yet, so it never gets to the line that sends a message to the server.  Put the `print sock.recv(256)` **after** the `sock.send`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I know that this will work, but I need to receive messages not exactly when I know that it must be sent by server.

Comment: Then you need a thread to process messages or a non-blocking processing loop.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115024/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-levshkatov).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: The issue with the code in the question is that it has an infinite loop at the top. None of the code below this will ever execute:

```
while True:
    print sock.recv(256)
```

(And apparently this particular server doesn't send a message until it's received one first, so it will never send anything.)

---

Here's a simple working example. If this doesn't help, you'll need to provide more context in your question.

Here's the client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 12345))
while True:
    print s.recv(256)
```

Corresponding server code:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 12345))
s.listen(0)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    conn.send("Hello")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioned, but I have this code on a client side

Comment: See my edit. It doesn't make much difference; the loop looks the same.

Comment: I updated my post with the whole code, maybe it will help, because I can't solve my problem using your answer